# How do you make a 2 divs(pages) scroll left and right with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello guys basically i have two divs which are two pages, One is the home page and the other page should come up when a button is clicked.

My method doesn't quite work yet and isn't correct because i want each div to be 100% width and height and the screen but it works when i use px. what do i do so that i don't have to use absolute values like the px instead percentages ?

This is my css so far:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#container {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden
}

#inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 800px; 
}

#home {
    position:absolute;
    width: 1300px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: red;
}

#member-home {
    position:absolute;
    left:1300px;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

This is the jquery:

```
function toggleDivs() {
    var $inner = $("#inner");

    // See which <divs> should be animated in/out.
    if ($inner.position().left == 0) {
        $inner.animate({
            left: "-1300px"
        });
    }
    else {
        $inner.animate({
            left: "0px"
        });
    }

}
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("button").bind("click", function() {
    toggleDivs();
});
 });
```

and the html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="inner">
        <div id="home">
            <button>Click</button>
        </div>
        <div id="member-home">
            <button>Click</button>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

This is the idea for my website (a full page scrolling website from left to right):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZTiJmclaRc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the width of the container to 200% and the two inners to 50% and make them float.

http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/TRk8U/

You can use a class and transition to avoid jquery animations:

```
var Slider = function() {
    this.$container = $('.container');

    this.init = function() {
        var self = this;
        $('.next').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            self.$container.addClass('shifted');
        });

        $('.prev').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            self.$container.removeClass('shifted');
        });
    }
    this.init();
}

var slider = new Slider();
```

And the CSS:

```
.container {
    margin-left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200%;
    min-height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: margin-left ease 500ms;
    -moz-transition: margin-left ease 500ms;
    -o-transition: margin-left ease 500ms;
    transition: margin-left ease 500ms;
}

.container.shifted {
     margin-left: -100%;
}

.page {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution you can use 100% width and height for the home and other pages.
You need to activate Jquery UI also for the effect i used in the answer.

**HTML**

```
 <div id="container">
<div id="inner">
    <div id="home">
        <button>Click</button>
    </div>
    <div id="member-home" style="display:none">
        <button>Click</button>
    </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
 $("button").click(function(){   
    var hideoptions = {  "direction" : "left",  "mode" : "hide"};
    var showoptions = {"direction" : "right","mode" : "show"};

    $("#home").toggle("slide", hideoptions, 1000);
    $("#member-home").toggle("slide", showoptions, 1000);

 });
```

**CSS**

```
 html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#container {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow:hidden
}

#inner {
position: relative;
width:100%; 
height:100%;
}

#home {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color: red;
}

#member-home {
position:absolute;
width: 100%;
height:100%;
background-color: green;
}
```

[**Working JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/D89PX/)